# Quais as principais diferenças entre as linguagens Ruby e Crystal?

Tags: ruby, característica-linguagem, crystal-lang

Vi há alguns dias, algumas informações sobre a linguagem Crystal, mas gostaria de compreender um pouco melhor quais as principais diferenças com Ruby.

Exemplos:

- Qual é mais rápido e leve no processamento?
- Tudo que é feito no Ruby pode ser feito no Crystal? Posso ainda usar os dois simultaneamente?
- Qual utiliza menos código?
- Qual possui mais fácil manutenção?
- Quais são as limitações de cada um?
- O que um faz melhor do que o outro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Qual é o mais rápido e leve no processamento?

Linguagens não costumam ter essa característica de forma marcante. Depende do algoritmo, do código feito, etc. Mas pela forma como cada uma funciona Crystal tende ser mais rápida.

> Tudo que é feito no Ruby pode ser feito no Crystal, posso ainda usar os dois em simultâneo?

Pode fazer tudo, afinal todas linguagens de programação podem fazer tudo. Mas elas não são compatíveis. Há semelhanças entre elas mais que outras linguagens, mas não foram feitas para serem complementares.

> Qual utiliza menos código?

Precisaria de uma melhor definição do que é isto, mas se tem menos caracteres no fonte não sei com certeza, acho que Ruby, e não importa também, isto não é relevante.

> Qual é o de mais fácil manutenção?

Isto depende do programador e não da linguagem. Depende um pouco de gosto, há quem afirme que tipagem estática é mais fácil, há quem diga o contrário.

> Quais são as limitações de cada um?

As principais é que Ruby precisa de máquina virtual para rodar a implementação padrão e Crystal não, é nativo. Crystal trabalha com tipagem basicamente estática e Ruby é dinâmica. Ruby não interage tão bem com C, possui mais dificuldades com concorrência e não possui um sistema sofisticado de macros. Parece-me que atualmente o GC de Crystal é pior que da maioria das implementações de Ruby.

> O que um faz melhor do que o outro?

Isto é opinião e depende do que deseja. O fato é que Ruby tem uma comunidade sólida, Crystal não. Crystal deve ser mais robusta por causa da tipagem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 *Isso depende do programador e não da linguagem...* Sempre foi assim e sempre será

Comment: #UzumakiArtanis sim sem dúvida acaba por sem uma pergunta quase sem resposta possivel vai sempre depender do programador

Comment: _"Qual permite expressar mais em menos linhas de código"_ não é uma pergunta relevante? Achei que fosse. Acho que foi isso que o AP quis saber.