# O que é a linguagem de programação Nim?

Tags: característica-linguagem

Eu estou começando a fuçar a linguagem [crystal](/questions/tagged/crystal) e aprender um pouco mais sobre e ver o porque dela existir. Pesquisei um pouco sobre sua performance e encontrei [este benchmark](https://web-frameworks-benchmark.netlify.app/result) com um resultado que me chamou atenção.

Vou listar os top 4 do *benchmark* que considera a linguagem e o *framework* web utilizado:

| Language | Framework | Request/Second(64) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nim (1.6) | httpbeast (0.4) | 191 442 |
| java (11) | activej (5.3) | 190 161 |
| javascript (16.15) | sifrr (0) | 180 150 |
| java (11) | undertow (2.2) | 176 517 |

Eu esperava no topo algo como Java, C ou C++ e apesar de não ligar muito pra performance, o resultado me chamou atenção por mencionar essa linguagem `nim`, que parece ser desconhecida ou ignorada pela nossa comunidade, mesmo tendo 14 anos (surgida em  2008). A tag [nim](/questions/tagged/nim) nem existe(ia) no SOpt.

Segundo a [documentação](https://nim-lang.org/):

> Efficient, expressive, elegant
> Nim is a statically typed compiled systems programming language. It combines successful concepts from mature languages like Python, Ada and Modula.

> pt-BR: Eficiente, expressivo, elegante
> Nim é uma linguagem de programação de sistemas compilados estaticamente tipados. Ele combina conceitos de sucesso de linguagens maduras como Python, Ada e Modula.

Analisei um pouco de seu código e a sintaxe realmente deixa qualquer dev Python se sentindo em casa (apesar de ter conceitos de Ada e Module), mas pelo (pouco) que li, me deu a impressão de que Nim é para o Python o que [Crystal é para o Ruby](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231772/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-as-linguagens-ruby-e-crystal/231791#231791). Seria o Python compilado e mais rápido e que ninguém conhece/usa. Posso estar falando besteira, mas quero que alguém me confirme :).

---

Como forma de entender a motivação/uso da linguagem:

- O que é Nim?
- O que essa linguagem tem a oferecer que lhe destacaria de outras linguagens como Crystal?
- É o Python com esteroides?

Comment: Me parece que o benchmark tem pouca relação com a linguagem, por isso C e C++ não estão no topo. A impressão que dá é que fizeram um cherry pick num nicho muito limitado, ou o benchmark foi feito pra um cenário muito específico. Provavelmente uma comparação até com "Linguagem pura + Servidor web puro" deve dar uma bela diferença, nem C precisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Benchmark* bem suspeito já que testa softwares completamente diferentes, por isso não pode tirar qualquer conclusão dele sobre as linguagens.

## A linguagem

A linguagem Nim é um pouco desconhecida, embora eu acompanhe há mais de uma década como aficionado por linguagens que sou.

#### É C

Bem grosso modo Nim é mais uma tentativa de fazer o tal do "C *done right*" que muitos tentam. Ainda bem que não é o C++, já que nesse caso nem passam perto em qualquer tentativa, desde o Java?!?!?!?. C é muito mais fácil, mas sempre tentam fazer algo que deixa de ser C, o Assembly portátil, como dizem. Pelo menos fica próximo em alguns pontos. Portanto faz sentido obter uma certa performance.

Ela é bem mais alto nível que C, mais até que C++ em certos pontos, mas ainda mantém certa simplicidade e poder. Ela adota algumas "modernidades" como OOP e funcional, mas é essencialmente imperativa.

#### Não é C

Nim, antiga Nimrod, em sua implementação padrão, a única conhecida até agora, realmente gera executáveis eficientes em tamanho e processamento, como C, em alguns casos tanto quanto ou até mais, ligeiramente, mas não está presente em todas as plataformas, por enquanto, e não é a íngua franca dos softwares, ainda que não fique longe pela compatibilidade enorme com C.

Curiosamente ela pode rodar em navegadores através de JavaScript, o que faz boa parte da filosofia original ser irrelevante.

#### Memória

Uma das vantagens dela em relação ao C é o gerenciamento de memória quase automático, opcionalmente, assim como C++ tem. O que não quer dizer que não tenha algum [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101).

Curiosamente ela alega ser apta para aplicações *hard real time* por isso, quando na verdade todas as linguagens só conseguem esse feito sem gerenciamento dem memória, armazenando de forma estática ou simulando isso, o que impede, e claro, torna desnecessário o gerenciamento.

Nos casos de usar um *garbage collector* completo que é onde ela fica mais fácil de usar, espere um *overhead* acima da média, é uma das poucas soluções que preza só pela facilidade. A maioria dos GCs modernos tendem a dar até mais eficiência em certo ponto que o gerenciamento manual (pode conseguir o mesmo manualmente, mas com um trabalho tão grande que escrever um GC e usar daria menos trabalho). E aí eu critico um pouco mais a decisão. É complicado mesclar código que usa GC ou não, até mesmo em GCs diferentes, isso é uma ingenuidade.

## Expressividade

Em alguns pontos ela é muito forte e avançada, permitindo escrever códigos expressivos sem adicionar custo, até melhor que C++. Obviamente que C pode obter o mesmo ganho, mas não com tanta expressividade ou sem perda de robustez que Nim tende a dar em grande parte dos casos.

O fato de ter [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) indica muita coisa sobre o comprometimento com desempenho e robustez, além de expressividade em certa medida. mas ela vai um pouco além em metaprogramação tendo formas de macros mais sofisticadas e seguras que C.

Um dos luxos da linguagem é a sintaxe, embora seja algo pouco relevante na escolha. Poucas coisas fazem dela algo extraordinário e que precisa ser usada mais que outras opções.

Minha maior crítica é a linguagem talvez seja a insensibilidade de caixa na sintaxe, achei que todos tínhamos aprendido sobre isso, ainda mais em linguagem de sistemas e não uma de brinquedo.

## Seriedade

Sem considerar o pequeno marketing que toda linguagem acaba fazendo (inclusive não acusa seus erros), ela sempre me pareceu bem pensada e de fato ajuda muito em várias situações sendo um C melhor, exceto pelo fato de não ser popular, e isso é uma enorme *feature* das outras linguagens.

Parece ser desenvolvida por pessoas que entendem do assunto e interessadas na boa evolução dela. De forma geração recomendo aprender um pouco, embora só ajude de fato a pessoa entender melhor se for nos meandros da linguagem, na superfície ela tem pouco a ensinar, e nem é objeto dela.

## Conclusão

Não vi nada inovador, a não ser a forma de juntar tudo, o que poderia ser bom, exceto que não gera nada muito desejável.

Se um programador Python se sente em casa então Python não é tão fácil quanto dizem. As pessoas ignoram que a dificuldade da linguagem está na semântica e não na sintaxe. Mas a comparação com Crystal faz algum sentido, mas Nim é bem mais C do que Python, até mesmo a sintaxe é bem diferente, só que não lembra tanto C, por isso talvez dê essa impressão, de forma enorme. Crystal não é tão C assim, não tem esse comprometimento todo. Nim é C mais fácil, bem pensado e até robusto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).